# Breaker tripping

Tags: lighting

So my first floor living room outlets are on a a single breaker, and for some reason it is tripping when a certain light in my basement is turned off. The problem doesn't happen every time, but I'd say it happens once every couple of days when the same one light (it is a 12T fluorescent fixture) is turned off, my completely separate 1st floor outlet breaker trips. The basement light is on a breaker with the rest of the basement ceiling lights. The two circuits are completely separate of one another. I'm not sure what could be causing this, any thoughts?? Any input appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Has anything changed around the time this started, or has this always been a problem?

Comment: I moved in not too long ago and it has been a problem I noticed a week or two after. We didn't use the room much at first until we bought a washer/dryer. The house was completely rewired to copper from aluminum before I moved in and it passed inspection. Its confusing with them being completely different circuits, but I'm positive that is the cause because whenever it happens I hear the breaker trip the moment I turn the light off.

Comment: The breaker that trips... Is it near the breaker for the fluorescent light? Is it a GFCI breaker? Does the wiring for the two circuits run in close proximity to each other?

Comment: No, it is not near the breaker with the light that is tripping it. And it is a combination AFCI breaker.

Comment: Does this fluorescent fixture have a magnetic (heavy lump o' metal) or electronic (light as a feather) ballast in it?  Also, what type of panel do you have installed, and what vintage is the CAFCI in it?

Comment: I recently changed 2 old magnetic ballasts that were defective so that was the first thing I checked but it was electronic, can a bad ballast cause anything like the issue I'm having? It is probably pretty old though. And I have a 100 amp, 30 circuit panel, the CAFCI is 120 volst, I;m assuming you were auto-corrected to vintage?

Comment: No I was not -- I need to know the panel type (brand name, breaker type) and the age of the CAFCI here...

Comment: Ok sorry, Siemens PL series 100 amp 30 circuit, Siemens 15 amp singe pole combination afci Model #US2:QA115AFCP

Comment: Both the living room outlets and basement lights run on that same model breaker if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical symptom of cross-circuit false-tripping due to the ballast causing EMI with breaker electronics.  I'd try replacing the breaker and ballast first; if that doesn't cure the problem, then there's likely a subtly faulty connection somewhere that's causing RF-rectification EMI.

Comment: Thank a lot man, switched out the ballast and it seems to be holding up. I played with the switch a little bit and no tripping from any breakers. Hoping it holds up now. Thanks again.'